# How to Change URL without refreshing the whole page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've been searching on stackOverFlow and etc. to see is there anyway to change URL without refreshing the whole page
I've found some answers but they didn't really help. 
Anyway, So I want to Change a `<div>` content when the URL is `someURL.com/?c=users&a=login`.
and You know it will load the functions that I've wrote.

for example look at the code below:

```php
<?php
    require_once 'model/Muser.php';
    $class = new user();
    switch ($action){
        case 'login':
            if($_POST){
                $data=$_POST['frm'];
                $password=sha1($data['password']);
                $user=$class->select_user($data['username']);
                if($user['password']==$password){

                }
            }
        break;
        case 'logout':

        break;

    }

    require_once "view/$controller/$action.php";
```

So when I type `someURL.com/?c=users&a=login` It will load the 
`view/users/login.php` page
but I want to only change the `<div>`'s content.
I've been figured this out using jquery but I want to when user types `someURL.com/?c=users&a=login` the `<div>` content change
or when clicked on some button the url  and `<div>`'s content change.

any solution ?

Comment: Typically you want to do this Client side, in otherwords with Javascript with the `history` API  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History  see the methods `pushState` and `replaceState`  And form submission implies using AJAX and JSON.

Comment: It's probably also useful to understand how the Server and Client are related (how they communicate to each other), and how state is maintained over HTTP.  These are core concepts that you really need to have a mastery of before getting into asynchronous communication between the  server and client.  Don't worry they are pretty simple to understand, but without that understanding nothing will make much sense.  Just google some stuff like "Client Server communication" and "HTTP and maintaining state"

Comment: What if you don't change the url but change the content only when a button is clicked by using javascript to listen to the click event on that button and use php to include a set of code. Some might consider a bad practice (i.e. mixing with php and js together). It's just an opinion from me. Or you could just use css to hide some content, and then toggle the display property when the button is clicked.

Comment: @IsraelObanijesu - IMO it's only bad if it's WET (write everything twice).  I put stuff were it makes sense to put it.  If it's a small piece of JS that deals with just this one page, there is no point making an extra file you have to keep track of.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `window.location.search` property in the browser to get the string of query params. Then you can make use of the `URLSearchParams` object to only get the params that you need. Based on the value you can change something on the page using jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  function updateDOMBasedOnQueryParams() {
    var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)

    if(urlParams.get('c') === '1') {
      $('.heading').text("'c' Query param has value 1")
    }
  }

  updateDOMBasedOnQueryParams()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 class="heading">Test heading</h1>
```

See: https://davidwalsh.name/query-string-javascript

Comment: Your code does not show an example of where you change the URL but prevent the page from reloading.

Comment: You can use the history api to push the new state. (ex: `window.history.pushState({test:1}, null, '?test=1')`)

Answer (score 0):

Can you define a DIV in some are our page, index.html for example and use the Ajax to put the result into DIV.

The solution without jQuery:

```
const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url='YOU_URL?param1=data1&param2=data2';
Http.open("GET", url);
Http.send();
Http.onreadystatechange=(e)=>{
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var htmlRequest = this.responseText;
        document.getElementById("DIV").innerHTML = htmlRequest;
    }
}
```